# Select count with in query through Crystal Reports

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

I'm trying to create a report where I have to get the top 10 facilities that have a specific action code. I'm using 3 different tables (customer.id) customers pertaining to those facilities, the facility information ( facility.id), and action code( action.id) I'm fairly new to writing queries so here is what

```
SELECT
    customer.id_NO,
    customer.id_CLIENT,
    facility.id_NAME_1 ,
    action.id_ACTION_CODE
FROM 
    CDS.action.id, CDS.customer.id, CDS.facility.id
WHERE 
    facility.id _NO = customer.id _CLIENT 
    AND action.id_CUSTOMER_NO = customer.id _NO
```

I want to count every time the action code 'CDQ' occurs per facility

```
SELECT COUNT ( action.id_ACTION_CODE)
FROM CDS.action.id
WHERE action.id_ACTION_CODE = 'CDQ'
```

Is it possible to get all in a single query? I'm using Crystal Reports

Comment: Three tables named `id` is highly suspicious.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a formula and use sum on this formula:

`If {action.id_ACTION_CODE} = "CDQ" Then 1 Else 0`